# Asymptotic behavior of $1/\ln n$ and $e^x-1$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

I have two asymptotic notation questions.

> Determine whether or not $\frac{1}{\ln(n)}=O(\frac{1}{n})$

My answer I put the statement is not true. A logarithmic function $\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ grows faster $\frac{1}{n}$ regardless of constant placed on $\frac{1}{n}$.

Thus $\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ not upper bound by $O(\frac{1}{n})$

My second question is

> Show that 
>   $e^x-1=O(x^2)$ is not true.

But I think it is true because using a graph you see

using a constant c=3 $e^x-1=O(3x^2)$ for $x>0.413$ but I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: No, it is not correct. $e^x-1$ grows much faster, because it is "an exponential". . "Using a graph" is not really convincing here.

Comment: Yes I think because e^x-1 is exponetial.

Comment: What is the definition of big O that you are using? Normally, this is defined with the limit of a ratio, and this should be a useful way to proceed in both questions.

Comment: I have f(x)=0(g(x)) f(x)<=Cg(x) for all x>N

Comment: Big O notation is the proper formalization for **growing slower/faster than.** So you should better use the formal definition, instead of intuitive arguments. In both cases, you could use l'hopital.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the power series
for $e^x$,
$e^x
> \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}
$,
so
$\frac{e^x}{x^n}
>\frac{x}{(n+1)!}
\to \infty
$,
so
$e^x
\ne O(x^n)$
for any $n$.